# How to send the result of a GET request in a POST request?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, post, get

I need to send a GET request to https://random.dog/woof.json. It  generate a random image and returns a json like this {
"fileSizeBytes": 1133380,
"url": "https://random.dog/8aff4e84-260d-4af0-9dc1-438d07ba3884.jpg"
} and I need save an image to my database. How can I  take "url" and send it with POST request?

Answer (score 0):

you can use node-fetch for server side requests.

It's similar to js' fetch api:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://random.dog/woof.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log("URL:", json[0].url);

 fetch('<url for your post request>', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { url: json[0].url },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(postRes => postRes.json())
      .then(postJson => console.log(postJson));  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
const https = require('https')


function getData(url: String) {
  const options = {
    hostname: 'exemple.com',
    path: '/your-endpoint',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }


  const req = https.request(options, (response: any) => {
    let body = '';

    response.on("data", (data: String) => {
      body += data;
    })

    response.on("end", () => {
      console.log(body)
    })

    response.on("error", (error: String) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  })

  req.write(JSON.stringify({
    url
  }));

  req.end()
}




https.get("https://random.dog/woof.json", (response: any) => {
  let body = '';
  response.on("data", (chunk: String) => {
    body += chunk;
  })
  response.on("end", () => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(body);
    getData(obj.url)
  })
});
```